# Keycloak stops without any reason using Bitnami Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, jboss, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I am trying to deploy a keycloak server with a postgres database attached using the [bitnami helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/keycloak) configured as follows with flux.

```
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: keycloak-release
  namespace: keycloak
spec:
  releaseName: keycloak
  targetNamespace: keycloak
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: keycloak
      version: 7.1.x
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: bitnami-repo
        namespace: flux-system
  interval: '10s'
  install:
    remediation:
      retries: 3
    timeout: '10m0s'
  values:
    image:
      debug: true
    containerPorts:
      http: 8080
      https: 8443
      management: 9990
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 256Mi
        cpu: 250m
      requests:
        memory: 256Mi
        cpu: 250m
    service:
      type: NodePort
      ports:
        postgresql: 5432
    postgresql:
      enabled: true
      auth:
        existingSecret: postgres-keycloak
    auth:
      existingSecret: keycloak-secret
    livenessProbe:
      enabled: true
      httpGet:
        path: /auth/
        port: http
      initialDelaySeconds: 300
      periodSeconds: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      failureThreshold: 3
      successThreshold: 1
    readinessProbe:
      enabled: true
      httpGet:
        path: /auth/realms/master
        port: http
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 1
      failureThreshold: 3
      successThreshold: 1
    extraEnvVars:
      - name: KEYCLOAK_ALWAYS_HTTPS
        value: "true"
      - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
        value: "true"
      - name: JAVA_OPTS_APPEND
        value: "-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=7200"
      - name : KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT
        value : "8080"
      - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT
        value: "8443"
    extraVolumes:
      - name: disable-theme-cache-volume
        configMap:
          name: disable-theme-cache
    extraVolumeMounts:
      - name: disable-theme-cache-volume
        mountPath: /opt/jboss/startup-scripts
```

However it seems there is a joss issue since the container never starts and the server stops without any particular reason.

[image: logs]

I assume the issue must lie in some jboss configuration but I do not see what. Any idea? :)

Comment: Did you manage to get it running?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that the resource limits might be too restrictive. At least memory should be more.

```yaml
resources:
      limits:
        memory: 256Mi
        cpu: 250m
      requests:
        memory: 256Mi
        cpu: 250m
```

Comment: Yes was part of the problem... However other misconfigs happened. I finally moved to the codecentric chart(https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/codecentric/keycloak) and it worked much better :)